# Jump Button in Unity for Canvas

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine

I am looking for a code or script in C# or Java to make my cube tagged as a `Player` jump, in below script.

I have written some code and attached it to a button on canvas, but the problem is when I press and hold the button, it keeps jumping and makes an infinitly high jump.

Here is my script written in C#

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DownstateButton : Button
{

    public void Update()
    {
        //A public function in the selectable class which button inherits from.
        if(IsPressed())
        {
            WhilePressed();
        }
    }

    public void WhilePressed()
    {
        var player =GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");

        player.transform.Translate(0, 1, 0);

        //It was for jump
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook the `PointerDown` (called when the button is pressed down) and `PointerUp` (button has been let go again) events from the UIButton and weight the translation of the position with `Time.deltaTime`, and you should be good to go. (`player.transform.Translate(0,1 * Time.deltaTime, 0)`, optionally multiply it with another factor for speed modulation.) References: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-events-and-event-triggers

EDIT: Yeah, some example code. First, I have an `EventTrigger` component on the button. I use this sothat I can hook the `PointerDown` and `PointerUp` events as described before. It looks like this in the inspector:

[image: unity]

(Use the "Add New Event Type" button to redirect the event calls.)
Then, I have this script on the button. The code speaks for itself.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class JumpButton : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool shouldJump = false;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        //Find the player
        var player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        //No player? exit out.
        if (player == null)
            return;
        //Is the jump button currently being pressed?
        if (shouldJump)
        {
            //Translate it upwards with time.
            player.transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, Time.deltaTime * 5, 0));
            //Make sure the Rigidbody is kinematic, or gravity will pull us down again
            if (player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic == false)
                player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        }
        //Not jumping anymore? reset the Rigidbody.
        else
            player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
    }

    //When the button is being pressed down, this function is called.
    public void ButtonPressedDown(BaseEventData e)
    {
        shouldJump = true;
    }

    //When the button is released again, this function is called.
    public void ButtonPressedUp(BaseEventData e)
    {
        shouldJump = false;
    }
}
```

The thing with switching to a kinematic rigidbody is optional, though. Also the speed can be adjusted with the multiplicative constant in the `Translate()` call. I tested this code with a standard cube, that has the `Player` tag and a `Rigidbody` on it, and it works fine.

Happy coding.

Comment: can you edit in my script?...i mean make it correct ...i will try it

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [unity coroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html).

At the start of the routine, you'd set (for example) "isJumping" (a bool), and then before you start your loop bit, you'd check if you are jumping by checking 'isJumping'.

If not "isJumping", set isJumping to true, do your jump, and then on the completion of the routine, set isJumping to false.

```
//untested (uncompiled) code written on the fly
bool isJumping = false;
IEnumerator doJump()
{
    if (!isJumping) {
        isJumping = true;
        // do jump (probably a loop)
        while (jumpCondition) {
            // jump instructions
            yield return
        }
        //unset isJumping, inside 'if' but after yield return 
        isJumping = false
    }
}
```

Note : code after `yield return` in a coroutine will only (probably) be run once, and only run as the coroutine exists (because no more yielding means the coroutine is at an end)